# Visual Studio Code: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, path

When I load files via Visual Studio Code, VScode can't find directory.

I can run code without issue with terminal, result is:

```
young@young-desktop:/media/young/5e7be152-8ed5-483d-a8e8-b3fecfa221dc/text/mycodehtml/pracdl/golbin/TensorFlow-Tutorials/10_RNN/ChatBot$ python text_load_text.py 
['fij\n', 'feijfaef\n', 'ef\n', 'awef\n', 'awe\n', 'g\n', 'aweg\n', 'ae\n', 'wg\n', 'awe\n', 'h\n', 'aw\n', 'h\n', 'aw\n', 'ef\n', 'aweg\n', 'wea\n', 'gaw\n', 'eg\n', '\n']
```

But with VScode:

```
young@young-desktop:/media/young/5e7be152-8ed5-483d-a8e8-b3fecfa221dc/text/mycodehtml/pracdl/golbin/TensorFlow-Tutorials$ cd /media/young/5e7be152-8ed5-483d-a8e8-b3fecfa221dc/text/mycodehtml/pracdl/golbin/TensorFlow-Tutorials ; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" /home/young/anaconda3/bin/python /home/young/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.6.0/pythonFiles/PythonTools/visualstudio_py_launcher.py /media/young/5e7be152-8ed5-483d-a8e8-b3fecfa221dc/text/mycodehtml/pracdl/golbin/TensorFlow-Tutorials 39707 34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14 RedirectOutput,RedirectOutput /media/young/5e7be152-8ed5-483d-a8e8-b3fecfa221dc/text/mycodehtml/pracdl/golbin/TensorFlow-Tutorials/10_RNN/ChatBot/text_load_text.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/young/5e7be152-8ed5-483d-a8e8-b3fecfa221dc/text/mycodehtml/pracdl/golbin/TensorFlow-Tutorials/10_RNN/ChatBot/text_load_text.py", line 8, in <module>
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
```

What causes this issue?

test.txt file originally is intended to be located in ./data/test.txt

So I tested

```
with open('./data/test.txt', 'r') as f:
```

But it failed with VScode

So I tried to move test.txt file to working directory with trying:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
```

and

```
with open('./test.txt', 'r') as f:
```

But all failed with VScode.

Comment: Note for your "current working directory", which is shown before the dollar sign in your first 2 code segments. Then your relative file path should get a little modification.

Comment: @GenoChen With absolute path like this with open('/media/young/5e7be152-8ed5-483d-a8e8-b3fecfa221dc/text/mycodehtml/pracdl/golbin/TensorFlow-Tutorials/10_RNN/ChatBot/test.txt', 'r') as f:, it worked in VScode. Would you guide how to set VScode to find reletive path?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [open() gives FileNotFoundError / IOError: '\[Errno 2\] No such file or directory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201928/open-gives-filenotfounderror-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 12):

First of all, get the directory of the module that is currently running by `os.path.dirname(__file__)`.
Then, you can join the relative path of your desire file to this directory path.

```
from os.path import dirname, join
current_dir = dirname(__file__)
file_path = join(current_dir, "./test.txt")
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this: enable the below option in your VSCode python setting

When executing a file in the terminal, whether to use execute in the file's directory, instead of the current open folder

[image]

Comment: didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 4):

I had an identical issue when trying to run a python script in VScode. Turns out, the function I needed to use was `os.chdir('path')`, and ***not*** `sys.path.append('path')`

This issue was specific to VScode. VScode was running the script out of the wrong directory. I found out what directory it was in using `print(os.listdir())`, and then changed the directory accordingly. Here's a snippet of the code that helped me resolve this.

```
import sys, os
print(os.listdir())
os.chdir('C:\\*****\\dir')
print(os.listdir())
```

Comment: my problem seems similar. As it's only happening in VS, and not from other IDEs, but where my issue is happening is not from my code. `open()` works fine, but `pd.read_csv()` is not opening files correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When I open this project, I opened it as "TensorFlow-Tutorials" folder.

So my working directory was:

```
young@young-desktop:/media/young/5e7be152-8ed5-483d-a8e8-b3fecfa221dc/text/mycodehtml/pracdl/golbin/TensorFlow-Tutorials
```

So "." indicates TensorFlow-Tutorials path
In this reason, following path fails to find file

```
with open('./test.txt', 'r') as f:
```

Solution is adding additional part to indicate my real target directory precisely:

```
with open("./10_RNN/ChatBot/test.txt", 'r') as f:
    x = f.readlines()
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the directory that your `.txt` file is on in your terminal or command prompt.

In your terminal `cd` into the directory that holds the `text` file and `.py` file , run the program and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

just place the txt file in the same folder where the .py file you are running the code from is.

i.e my code is in dile.py which is in a folder "python program". Place the txt file in that folder

Answer (score 0):

By default, VS Code runs the program such that the current working directory is the workspace folder. So when the program is being run, the integrated terminal `cd` to that folder ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58177323/3002584)), and expects to find files over there.

To make the program run in the **current** working directory, we can add `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` to `launch.json` file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [                
                    
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"        
            
        }
    ]
}
```

Now go back to your program file and run it (don't accidently try to run `launch.json` itself, it won't work :).